# The collected works of John von Neumann

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, applied-mathematics

Might there be an online collection of John von Neumann's collected works in pdf format? I'm particularly interested in his approach to applied mathematics(ex. shockwaves, hydrodynamics).

**Note:** I have found his collected works in [hardcover format on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0080095720).

Comment: the entire 6-volume set costs $6000 hard copy; Google has digitized it, but for copyright reasons it is not made available.

Comment: This is what libraries are for... Books cost money, and von Neumann is not public domain yet.. Why expect things to be freely available?

Comment: How many university libraries have the collected works of John von Neumann? At ~6000 euros this is pretty expensive. Couldn't the US or European government purchase the copyright from Pergamon Press?

Comment: Mathematics is not just about results. In my opinion, mathematics is mainly about intuitions and the struggle to find the right abstractions. So the collected works of an excellent mathematician may be of great value to modern mathematicians if used in an intelligent manner.

Comment: First 5 volumes are available on Genesis.

Comment: By contrast, the papers of Einstein are all online: https://www.aip.org/history-programs/news/einstein-papers-now-online

Comment: Considering the world wide efforts in digitalizing old materials, it's really a shame JvN works are not available; neither as reprints, nor as new editions, paperback or hardcover or eBooks. Really strange in fact what exactly is going on with the copyright. Anything >$1k for six books is out of anyone's budget, but these are not new books, they are dated. Search Archive Books, some are there, but not from the collected works package.